# Thymeleaf replace URL query elements(Path variables)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url, thymeleaf

Hope this is not a dublicate. I creating a simple MVC clothes shop, and having trouble creating a dynamic URL with Thymeleaf.There is a global categories(men,women) and subcategories for every type of clothes(i.e Shoes: Loafers, Sneakers, Crocs, etc), and my goal is to filter them by sex(gender?) or by sex and type.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{sex}", "/{sex}/{type}",""})
public String filterBySex(@PathVariable(value = "sex", required = false) String sex,
                          @PathVariable(value = "type", required = false) String type,
                          Model model) {
    List<Product> filteredProducts;
    if (sex!=null && type==null) {
        filteredProducts = productRepository.findBySex(sex);
        model.addAttribute("products",filteredProducts);
        return "index";
    } else if (sex!=null && type != null) {
        filteredProducts = productRepository.findBySexAndCategoryName(sex,type);
        model.addAttribute("products",filteredProducts);
        return "index";
    }
    filteredProducts = (List<Product>) productRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("products",filteredProducts);
    return "index";
}
```

And this is a fragment of the index page:

```
<header class="navbar-expand">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between" id="topNavbar">
      <div class="col-auto p-0">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/main/male}">Мужчинам</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/main/female}">Женщинам</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto p-0">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdown-profile"
               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Профиль
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-shoes">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Placeholder</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Корзина</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="bottomNavbar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown" href="#">Новинки</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdown-clothes"
             data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Одежда
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-clothes">
            <a class="dropdown-item" th:each="item:${outerwear}" th:text="${item.name}"
               th:href="@{${'~'+ #httpServletRequest.requestURI}+'/'+${item.name}}">Action</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdown-shoes"
             data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Обувь
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-shoes">
            <a class="dropdown-item" th:each="item:${shoes}" th:text="${item.name}"
               th:href="@{${'~'+ #httpServletRequest.requestURI}+'/'+${item.name}}">Placeholder</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I expect:

1. When I select a global category "Мужчины" URL should be `http://localhost:8080/main/male`.
2. When I click on subcategory for example "Sneakers" from type `shoes` URL should be `http://localhost:8080/main/male/Sneakers`

The problem is when I click on subcategory it just appends the subcategory. For example, I click on "Мужчины"->Loafers->Sneakers. I expect `http://localhost:8080/main/male/Sneakers`. Instead I get `http://localhost:8080/main/male/Loafers/Sneakers`

Is there any way to replace a part of URL? I've read some docs about context-relative URLs, but that did not help.

Comment: you can create a class implementing Filter ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html ). Note also that support for httpServletRequest in expressions is removed starting with Thymeleaf 3.1.

Comment: Firstly, you store a base URL (http://localhost:8080/main) in a global variable. Then, according to your selection, you just use base URL and concatenate it with the new dynamic URL. So that, your base URL will be always as a constant. e.g. path=baseurl + “/male/sneakers”; on next selection path=baseurl + “/male/loafers”.